# Not all data is being shown in my chart controls

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use Charts from Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the code used on page load in .aspx.vb file

```
Dim o_cmd As SqlCommand
Dim o_reader As SqlDataReader

Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
Dim myCommand As SqlDataAdapter

o_Con = New SqlConnection(Gbl.DataS)
o_Con.Open()
S_Sql = "SELECT     Exam, ResultGrade FROM RegAppear WHERE (UID=" & Val(Session("UID")) & ")"
o_cmd = New SqlCommand(S_Sql, o_Con)
o_reader = o_cmd.ExecuteReader
Chart1.Series("Default").Points.DataBindXY(o_reader, "Exam", o_reader, "ResultGrade")
o_reader.Close()
o_Con.Close()
```

Here is the code from aspx file

```
   <asp:chart id="Chart1" runat="server" BackColor="#D3DFF0" 
        BorderColor="26, 59, 105" Palette="BrightPastel" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid" 
        BackSecondaryColor="White" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BorderWidth="2" 
        Width="600px" RightToLeft="Yes" >
   <titles>
   <asp:Title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0" Font="Trebuchet MS, 14.25pt, style=Bold" ShadowOffset="3" Text="Performance in Different Subjects" ForeColor="26, 59, 105">
   </asp:Title>
   </titles>
   <legends>
   <asp:Legend Enabled="False" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default"  BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"></asp:Legend>
   </legends>
  <borderskin SkinStyle="Emboss"></borderskin>
 <series>
 <asp:Series IsValueShownAsLabel="True" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Default" 
               CustomProperties="LabelStyle=Bottom" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" 
               LabelFormat="#"></asp:Series>
  </series>
 <chartareas>
 <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="64, 165, 191, 228" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
    <axisy2 Enabled="False"></axisy2>
    <axisx2 Enabled="False"></axisx2>
    <area3dstyle Rotation="10" Perspective="10" Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False" WallWidth="0" IsClustered="False" />
    <axisy LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="False" ArrowStyle="Triangle" LabelAutoFitStyle="None">
    <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
    </axisy>
    <axisx LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="True" ArrowStyle="Triangle" IsReversed="False" TextOrientation="Auto" LabelAutoFitStyle="LabelsAngleStep90" IsInterlaced="True" LogarithmBase="10">
    <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
    </axisx>
    </asp:ChartArea>
    </chartareas>
</asp:chart>
```

Here is the output on Browser-

[image]

Problem is on the X axis where only alternative names of the exams are seen. Here is the list of exams I see when query is made directly to the database but as seen in the image alternative names are shown in graph.

```
COMED K MOCK- 1 2012
AIIMS Nov-2009 
AIIMS Nov-2007 
AIIMS May-2006 
APPG- 2008 
APPG- 2009
2012-13- Aimmds- Periodontics-1
2012-13- Aimmds- Microbiology-2
2012-13- Aimmds- Microbiology-1
C33- AimMDS2012-AIIMS Mock N2
2012-13- Aimmds- Gen Histo And embryology
```

Do we have a way to make sure all the name of exams are shown in the x axis ?

Comment: `I` (when referring to yourself) is always capitalized. Also, there is no space between the end of a sentence and the period (or question mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find the solution.. Adding here so that in future other can also use..
By changing AxisX internal all names of series are seen

Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1

Comment: This was driving me nuts.  I couldn't figure out why not all the series were displaying.  Thanks for this simple fix!